# How to find last bit set in a number (SWI-Prolog)?

Tags: prolog

I need to write a piece of code whose responsibility is to compute position of the last bit set in a given number.

Here is one of my attempts:

```
find_last_bit_set(Value, Result) :-
    do_find_last_bit_set(Value, -1, Result).
do_find_last_bit_set(0, R, R).
do_find_last_bit_set(Value, Result, R) :-
    Y #= Value // 2,
    Result1 is Result + 1,
    do_find_last_bit_set(Y, Result1, R).
```

However the problem is that the above code never stops. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Better to avoid mixing is/2 and (#=)/2... and look out for msb/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After succeeding the fist clause of `do_find_last_bit_set/3`, nothing is stopping the engine to attempt further solutions by exploring the second clause which is not guarded against `Value` being 0.

You might want to add a guard `Value #\= 0` as the first goal of the second clause of `do_find_last_bit_set/3`:

```
do_find_last_bit_set(0, R, R).
do_find_last_bit_set(Value, Result, R) :-
    Value #\= 0,
    Y #= Value // 2,
    Result1 is Result + 1,
    do_find_last_bit_set(Y, Result1, R).
```

Comment: @krzysieb: and of course `LastBitSet is floor(log(Value)/log(2))`